# Antialiased curves at cocos2dx

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, antialiasing, cocos2d-x-3.0

Does anybody know any solution for anti-aliasing problem at cocos2dx?

**DrawNode**

I can use standart DrawNode class and draw cardinal splines, which will be transformed to a set of polygons. Something like this:

```
node = DrawNode::create(9);
node->clear();
node->drawCardinalSpline(pts, tension, segments, Color4F::RED);
for (int i = 0; i < pts->count(); ++i) {
    node->drawPoint(pts->getControlPointAtIndex(i), 10, Color4F::BLUE);
}
```

[image]

this picture has folowing artefacts:

- stepped curve borders (aliasing)
- some cutted holes inside line. (WTF?)
  I tried :
- varry segment number (at screenshot - tension = 0, segments = 120), but this didn't help.
- Tried to draw it at huge size and then use scaling - didn't work.
- Take a bitmap with RenderTexture and set anti aliasing flag on the resulted sprite - no.
- smoothstep shader (many times mentioned at forum, for example, see here)
  All of this lead to elumination of only small fraction of all the artifacts.

**Drawing with triangles**
I can draw all the things directly by calculating triangles verticies. I has a working solution with this. It looks like this:[image]

Look at the curved line. (screen captured from android device). In order to make this, I used custom DrawNode, because I can't set different opacity for different triangle vertex. My class AlphaNode for that:

- [AlphaNode.h](https://gist.github.com/lifeisdream/152de068437ba929d5585ee369a5d87c)
- [AlphaNode.cpp](https://gist.github.com/lifeisdream/45d216b7b53f4214edb540626f64d810)

And then I just fill the Vec2 array of vertices and for every 3 vertices call drawTriangle from my AlphaNode class. At this approach I get antialiasing by manually set alpha to 0 on borderline vertices:
[image]

I think I explain the idea clear (but if not I could make separate compilable solution with all the needed code a little bit latter).

This solutions definitely allow me to obtain any graphics I want. But do I really need engine, if I draw triangles by myself?
(and also if anyone have something to say about my custom draw node limitations, please - say)

**LibSkia**

Well. I can link to libskia on android. Make some path objects on skia side (skia will make them anti-aliased). Then export it to bitmap. Then draw with cocos. But again.. why do I need cocos in that case?

I will try to search for another way. I will be very happy from every piece of help. And I really think its an important feature for 2-3 d engine - ability to draw lines... How do you solved this issue for your project? How do you draw curves?

P.S. Link to [question](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/final-topic-about-anti-aliasing-disease/37666) at cocos-forum with similar links.

Comment: Unfortunately, DrawNode doesn't support anti-aliasing.

Comment: Yeap, I've got that =( But its open source. so the true question is - what we can do about it? =)

Comment: Implement it by yourself (as I can see you already started doing) or use different rendering method. You can try OpenCV, I tried it but only for calculations, not for rendering. It could be hard to mix with cocos2d-x. Fingers crossed for your work, I'd use that if it'll be working.

Comment: Thanks. Any links about the practical algorithms?